# Print result of IntStream average

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I'm currently learning about streams and am using the .average function to figure out the average of some integers that are input using the scanner. 
The problem I'm running into is how to format the output so that it doesn't say optional double.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ClassAverage {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        grades.add(scan.nextInt());

        if (scan.equals("end")) {
            {
                break;
            }

        }
        grades.forEach(System.out::println);

    }

    System.out.println("" + grades.stream()
            .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
            .average());

}
}
```

This is the output I'm getting

```
 OptionalDouble[88.0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`average()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#average()) returns an [`OptionalDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/OptionalDouble.html) object, not a `double`.

If you've got a single action to perform over the result, like printing it, you could use [`ifPresent​(DoubleConsumer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/OptionalDouble.html#ifPresent(java.util.function.DoubleConsumer)):

```
grades.stream()
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        .average()
        .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Otherwise,

```
OptionalDouble optionalAverage = grades.stream()
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        .average();

if (optionalAverage.isPresent()) {
    double average = optionalAverage.getAsDouble();
    System.out.println(average);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/OptionalDouble.html#orElse(double)) to retrieve the actual `double` value wrapped by the `OptionalDouble`.

Doing so you would also decide a default value when the `Optional` is empty (in this case I used `0.0`):

```
System.out.println("" + grades.stream()
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        .average()
        .orElse(0.0)
);
```

Comment: I'd return `Double.NaN` instead of `0.0` because with zero elements, the average is truly not defined, and 0.0 can be confusing if input values can go negative).